# Android Studio Listview with radio button value - How to check radio button and get value?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-radiobutton

Please help..

i have listview with radio button value but my problem is i dont know to check each radio button and get the value..

this is my **checkoutlayout1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:background="#fffff1f1">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fffff1f1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fffddbd7"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="STEP 1 OF 3 - DELIVERY INFORMATION"
                    android:id="@+id/textStep"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff949596"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Please select the preferred shipping method to use on this order."
                    android:id="@+id/textShipping"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.example.administrator.mosbeau.ExpandableHeightListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/shippinglist"
                    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                    android:background="#fffff1f1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textnote"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout4"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="CONTINUE"
                android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/cfa245_button"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in my layout i have this listview

```
 <com.example.administrator.mosbeau.ExpandableHeightListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/shippinglist"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:background="#fffff1f1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textnote"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

and this is my **shippingrate_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fffff1f1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fffff1f1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textconfigurationid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="configuration_id"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="shipping_title"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:id="@+id/radioShippingtitle" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/shipping_icon"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioShippingtitle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioShippingtitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:maxHeight="20dp"
                android:maxWidth="60dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textPrice"
                android:text="shipping_price"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shipping_icon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shipping_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:minHeight="32dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textDesc"
                android:text="shipping_desc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioShippingtitle"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my item i have this radio

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="shipping_title"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:id="@+id/radioShippingtitle" />
```

i pass value to my listview item with my **checkoutFragment1.java**

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 11/7/2015.
 */
public class CheckoutFragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static CheckoutFragment1 newInstance(String customersid, String countryid, String weightotal, String subtotal, String stateid) {
        CheckoutFragment1 fragment = new CheckoutFragment1();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("customersid", customersid);
        bundle.putString("countryid", countryid);
        bundle.putString("weightotal", weightotal);
        bundle.putString("subtotal", subtotal);
        bundle.putString("stateid", stateid);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public CheckoutFragment1 () {
    }

    String customersid, countryid, weightotal, subtotal, stateid;

    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://shop.mosbeau.com.ph/android/";

    String myJSONShippingRate;
    JSONArray jsonarrayShippingRate;

    ExpandableHeightListView shippingratelistview;
    ListViewAdapterShipping shippingrateadapter;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> shippingratearraylist;
    public static String configuration_id = "configuration_id";
    public static String shipping_title = "shipping_title";
    public static String shipping_icon = "shipping_icon";
    public static String shipping_price = "shipping_price";
    public static String shipping_desc = "shipping_desc";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkoutlayout1, container, false);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        if(isConnected){
            getShippingRate();
        }else{
            nointernet();
        }

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            String ccustomersid = getArguments().getString("customersid");
            String ccountryid = getArguments().getString("countryid");
            String cweightotal = getArguments().getString("weightotal");
            String csubtotal = getArguments().getString("subtotal");
            String cstateid = getArguments().getString("stateid");

            customersid = ccustomersid;
            countryid = ccountryid;
            weightotal = cweightotal;
            subtotal = csubtotal;
            stateid = cstateid;
        }

        shippingratelistview = new ExpandableHeightListView(getActivity());
        shippingratelistview = (ExpandableHeightListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shippinglist);

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"custoid: "+customersid+" countryid: "+countryid+" weight: "+weightotal+"subtotal: "+subtotal+" stateid: "+stateid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        showGlobalContextActionBar();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle("CHECKOUT");
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void getShippingRate(){
        class DownloadJSONShippingRate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                /*mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                // Set progressdialog title
                //mProgressDialog.setTitle(cname);
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();*/
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, null, true, false);
                mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customersid", customersid));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryid", countryid));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stateid", stateid));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weightotal", weightotal));
                dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subtotal", subtotal));

                HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "shippingrate.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String shippingrateresult = null;
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    shippingrateresult = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return shippingrateresult;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String shippingrateresult){
                myJSONShippingRate=shippingrateresult;

                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    JSONObject jsonObjcart = new JSONObject(myJSONShippingRate);
                    jsonarrayShippingRate = jsonObjcart.getJSONArray("shippingrate");
                    shippingratearraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    int qtySum = 0, qtyNum, tqtySum;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarrayShippingRate.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> lmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject p = jsonarrayShippingRate.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        lmap.put("configuration_id", p.getString("configuration_id"));
                        lmap.put("shipping_title", p.getString("shipping_title"));
                        lmap.put("shipping_desc", p.getString("shipping_desc"));
                        lmap.put("shipping_icon", p.getString("shipping_icon"));
                        lmap.put("shipping_price", p.getString("shipping_price"));

                        shippingratearraylist.add(lmap);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                shippingrateadapter = new ListViewAdapterShipping(getActivity(), shippingratearraylist);
                shippingratelistview.setAdapter(shippingrateadapter);
                shippingratelistview.setExpanded(true);

                // Close the progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        DownloadJSONShippingRate g = new DownloadJSONShippingRate();
        g.execute();
    }

    public void nointernet(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("There seems to be a problem with your connection.");
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Edit Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }

        });
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Reload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                HomeFragment homefragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, homefragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

and my **listviewadaptershipping.java**

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class ListViewAdapterShipping extends BaseAdapter {

    boolean expanded = false;

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapterShipping(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView configuration_id;
        RadioButton shipping_title;
        ImageView shipping_icon;
        TextView shipping_price;
        TextView shipping_desc;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shippingrate_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in product_gridview_item.xml
        configuration_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textconfigurationid);
        shipping_title = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioShippingtitle);
        shipping_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shipping_icon);
        shipping_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        shipping_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        configuration_id.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.configuration_id));
        shipping_title.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_title));
        shipping_price.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_price));
        shipping_desc.setText(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_desc));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        Glide.with(context).load(resultp.get(CheckoutFragment1.shipping_icon)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(shipping_icon);
        int color = 0xffffffff;
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**now the problem is i want to click the radio button and get the textconfigurationid and pass to variable**

please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your problem correctly, but what i guess you want to get value of RadioButton and TextView(textconfigurationid) to store in a variable.

You can handle your click events in your `getView` method in the BaseAdapter.
Something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     //***
              Your code here..
                                 ***//      
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    //You can get value of radio button and textview like this.
    Boolean radioValue = shipping_title.isChecked();
    int configId = configuration_id.getText();

    return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using radioButton.isChecked(), it will tell you whether the radio button is checked or not. Also, you can use

```
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code..

```
mconfiguration_id = configuration_id.getText().toString();
        shipping_title.setTag(mconfiguration_id);
        shipping_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;

                String mconfiguration_id;
                mconfiguration_id = v.getTag().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, mconfiguration_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        if(mSelectedPosition != position){
            shipping_title.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            shipping_title.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && shipping_title != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = shipping_title;
            }
        }
```